# Detect failing USB hard drive automatically

Tags: hard-drive, cron, automation, raspbian

I Have a Raspberry Pi which has one USB external hard drive attached to it (via a separatly powered USB hub). The thing is that sometimes this disk becomes unresponsive (I can't access its mounted directories any more). A quick fix I found for this is just to restart the Pi.

The Pi is running a minor home server so it would be nice to have it always online, but 100% availability isn't so important. What's more important for me is that I don't have to think about it or tinker with it every so often.

So... My goal is to automate this. Currently my idea is to have a cron job running every few minutes to detect the unresponsive disk and if so, to reboot the Pi. The only thing I'm not sure about is how to detect when it becomes unresponsive, what's the best approach.

Comment: Why not fix the actual problem and get a drive that isn't randomly failing?

Comment: 1) I don't want to invest more money into this setup. 2) The drive is actually ok when hooked up to a computer. My guess is that it isn't getting enough power from the usb hub, which again brings me to step 1. Just to detect this and have the Pi automatically restart is more than enough for me.

Comment: if the drive is freezing because it's not getting enough power, eventually it is either going to corrupt your data, or cause the drive to fail.

Comment: Even if this is the case, I'm actually not worried about either. The data on it is temporary and not really so important. If I lose it, I lose it. And the drive... Well I have some 4 or 5 more just sitting in a closet and not doing anything. If it dies, I'll just replace it with another. But I doubt it's really doing much damage since this failure doesn't happen that often, once every few weeks or so.